# Django check if query-set response is empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to check if items queryset is empty or not.

```
order = Order.objects.get(customer=request.user.customer)
items = order.orderitem_set.all() #check if items length is 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check this with [**`.exists()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists):

```
order = Order.objects.get(customer=request.user.customer, complete=False)
flag = order.orderitem_set.exists()  # True if at least one item
```